# How to add to ActionParameters collection from an IRouteConstraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to add an object to the ActionParameters collection from within an IRouteConstraint implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the RouteValueDictionary of the request but you should not be doing this with a route constraint.

Perhaps you could explain what it is you are trying to achieve and I can provide a better answer.

Comment: I have a generic controller with actions which require an enum. I'm using the route constraint to ensure that a string in the url can be converted into the enum and add it to the RouteValueDictionary so it can then be added to the ActionPatameters collection.

Comment: @devlife, you should be doing this as part of your route configuration. e.g. mycontroller/myaction/{enumvalue} along with your route constraint to ensure the route is only matched if a valid enumvalue is used.

Comment: I am including the enum value as a string and then trying to parse the value into the enum.  So if it can't be parsed into the enum then the restriction returns false.